# Is there a way to check if the attachment send is either a image or video in discord.py?

Tags: discord.py, pycord

I am making a bot that converts media.xxxx.net into cdn.xxxx.com links. This works perfectly for videos but as a side effect, it also converts images which is an undesirable effect.

One way would explicitly tell the bot which formats (mp4, MOV etc) to convert and leave the other formats but considering the amount of formats there are for video file, I think it is necessary but I can't come up with any other way.

Here is the code I wrote

```
if message.content.startswith('https://media') and not message.content.endswith('jpg') and not message.content.endswith('png') and not message.content.endswith('gif') and not message.content.endswith('webp'):
     message.content.replace('media', 'cdn').replace('net', 'com') 
     await message.delete()
```

Here I was trying to make the bot ignore the most common picture formats but it is just looking like a mess as I add more and more formats.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check for the file type of the attachments using the [`content_type` attribute](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=message#discord.Attachment.content_type) and if they are an image you can tell it to ignore it.

```py
for att in message.attachments:
    if att.content_type.startswith("video"):
        new_url = message.content.replace('media', 'cdn').replace('net', 'com')
        await message.channel.send(new_url)
        await message.delete()
```

Comment: Because most of the videos/images are shared through links, the content_type returns an empty list.

Comment: how can the content type return empty? it needs to be a mime format. i am not sure if discord treats link embeds as attachments or not but even if they do they still need to be of a certain mime type. so something like "video/mp4" or "image/jpeg"

Comment: When I used it and print out the result it returned a  [ ]
I think Discord doesn't treat link embeds as attachments

Answer (score -1):

Instead of checking for if the URL does not ends with the image format, check if  the URL ends with a video format.

```
message_text = message.content
if message_text.find('https://media.discordapp.net') != -1 and message_text.find('.mp4') != -1:
     new_url = message_text.replace('https://media.discordapp.net','https://cdn.discordapp.com')
     await message.channel.send(new_url) 
     await message.delete()
```

Comment: The problem is there is no single used video format in discord (MOV, 3gp etc)

Answer (score -2):

To make my code cleaner, I made a list and added all the possible formats in there, it is basically the same **LOGIC** as my previous way but it is a lot cleaner and more manageable.

```
formats=['png', 'jpg', 'gif' , 'webp', 'jpeg', 'jpg' , 'jpeg' ,'jfif' ,'pjpeg' , 'pjp', 'svg', 'bmp']
msg = message.content

if message.content.startswith('https://media'): 
     if any(word in msg for word in formats):
      return
```

So it will check for the word in the link, if it finds any one of the formats (jpg, png), it will return instead of running the next piece of code