# (Discord.py) Is there any way to check that sent attachment is image?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Im making a image-editing bot and i cant figure out how to check if sent attachment is image.

So im wondering if theres any way to check it, thanks for answer.

I tried:

```py
if = ctx.message.attachments[0].image == True:
   # do stuff

But sadly got error (i was expecting it!!!!)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to check if the attachment send is either a image or video in discord.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70982261/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-the-attachment-send-is-either-a-image-or-video-in-dis)

Comment: I was checking this before, but sadly this solution didnt work for me. So no.

Answer (score 1):

The [`discord.Attachment`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=attachment#discord.Attachment) class has a [`content_type`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=attachment#discord.Attachment.content_type) attribute that contains the MIME-type of the attachment. For example, if the user uploads a `.png` file, the value of this will be `"image/png"`. Checking if it starts with `"image/"` is probably good enough for your use-case, unless you only want to allow very specific types of images.

Note: this field can be `None` if the value is unknown for whatever reason.